# Postgres - can't acces database, no acces

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I am trying to access my postgres database but I get a permission denied error. I created database + table (was created in python but it is there):

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# create user lukasz1 with encrypted password '<password>';
postgres=# create database mydatabase owner lukasz1;
```

So far so good:

```
                                  List of databases
    Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 mydatabase | lukasz1  | UTF8     | pl_PL.UTF-8 | pl_PL.UTF-8 | =Tc/lukasz1          +
            |          |          |             |             | lukasz1=CTc/lukasz1
 postgres   | postgres | UTF8     | pl_PL.UTF-8 | pl_PL.UTF-8 | 
 template0  | postgres | UTF8     | pl_PL.UTF-8 | pl_PL.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1  | postgres | UTF8     | pl_PL.UTF-8 | pl_PL.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

and lukasz1 is an owner of mydatabase.

But when I try to connect it I am get "permission denied".

I can't even select from my table to view it as permission is denied:

```
mydatabase=> select article_id from articles;
```

> ERROR: permission denied for table articles

I checked multiple answers to similar questions and tried checking user valid_until and got an empty values in that column:

```
mydatabase=> select usename, valuntil from pg_user;
 usename  | valuntil 
----------+----------
 postgres | 
 lukasz   | 
 lukasz1  | 
(3 rows)
```

In other question I found that pgAdmin4 can bug this and I should change valid until to infinity,which I tried but without any result as permission was denied to make this change.

```
mydatabase=> alter user lukasz1 valid until 'infinity';
ERROR:  permission denied
```

I checked privileges of the users and got this:

```
postgres=# select * from pg_user;
 usename  | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | userepl | usebypassrls |  passwd  | valuntil | useconfig 
----------+----------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+----------+----------+-----------
 postgres |       10 | t           | t        | t       | t            | ******** |          | 
 lukasz   |    16384 | f           | f        | f       | f            | ******** |          | 
 lukasz1  |    17256 | f           | f        | f       | f            | ******** |          | 
 lukasz2  |    17437 | f           | f        | f       | f            | ******** |          | 
(4 rows)
```

I turned out that even though lukasz1 is owner of the mydatabase that account can't do anything with databse.

Next thing I checked was default access privileges which was completly empty:

```
mydatabase=> \ddp
         Default access privileges
 Owner | Schema | Type | Access privileges 
-------+--------+------+-------------------
(0 rows)
```

I tried changing password but it changed nothing.

```
ALTER USER lukasz1 WITH PASSWORD '<new password>';
```

I tried to create public schema but wasn't allowed as permission was denied:

```
mydatabase=> create schema public;
ERROR:  permission denied for database mydatabase
```

All of that resulted, that docker container with web cannot access container with db as

```
password authentication failed for user "lukasz1"
```

I cannot even view hba_file:

```
mydatabase=> show hba_file;
ERROR:  must be superuser or a member of pg_read_all_settings to examine "hba_file"
```

Can anyone please advice how can I make this work?

**EDIT:**
I checked the logins and were able to create lukasz as superuser.

```
 usename  | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | userepl | usebypassrls 
 lukasz   |    16384 | f           | t        | f       | f
```

When using his credentials I am able to create tables, insert data into it etc.

```
psql -d mydatabase -U lukasz -W -c "insert into articles values (1, 'Łukasz', 'lukasz', 'title','tekst')"
```

But after creating containers I still get

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "lukasz"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydatabase
      - POSTGRES_USER=lukasz
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - backend

  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - backend


networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
    name: backend
```

setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'lukasz',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

sqlalchemy engine:

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql://lukasz:password@db:5432/mydatabase")
```

Comment: Who are you connecting as in the above examples? Who created table `articles`? Do you have more then one instance of Postgres running? If so are you sure you are connecting to correct instance? When troubleshooting this use same explicit connection string for all connections. For instance: `'psql -d db_name -U some_name -p some_port -h some_host`.

Comment: Please see edit for update

Comment: Looks like a Docker thing and I don't know enough about Docker to be of help. I would add the the `environment:` variables may need to be changed to ones `libpq` recognizes:[Env variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)